# How to use Glibc feature test macros?

Tags: c, linux, libc

I'd line to use `pthread_setname_np` function if it's available. Code from the manpage:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
   #include <pthread.h>
   int pthread_setname_np(pthread_t thread, const char *name);
   int pthread_getname_np(pthread_t thread,
                          char *name, size_t len);
```

Is it safe to just do like that (no includes, no defines):

```
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "mythread");
#endif
```

Includes are not needed because the C++ `#include <thread>` that I use seems to pull `pthreads`. The `_GNU_SOURCE` is always enabled in `libstdc++`, and if it gets disabled - the code will still compile.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you read [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes. It's about controlling what the standard library provides. I'm interested in activating of a feature of my program depending on how the build was set up.

Comment: It seems this question is tag'd as `c` but the actual question discussed `c++`.   These are different languages.  Please pick one.

Comment: @user3629249, it's about `glibc`'s feature test macros. I wouldn't tag it with `c` or `c++` at all, but I figured that C pogrammers are more familiar with glibc and Linux (and there are more of C programmers in general).

Answer (score 4):

> Is it safe to just do like that (no includes, no defines):

Yes. It's safe as long as you include `<pthread.h>` which provides the prototype for `pthread_setname_np`.

> Includes are not needed because the C++ #include  that I use seems to pull pthreads.

`libc++` uses pthreads library underneath. So, it works with `pthread.h`. But that doesn't mean `pthread.h` isn't needed if you include `<thread>`. What if `libc++` changes the underlying mechanism to implement threads? So, it's not safe to by pass `pthread.h` just because it happens to be available by other means.